# Сделать картинку квадратной: дорисовать белые поля по бокам

Tags: java, изображения

Добрый день, Хеш.

Суть задачи. После скачки картинки, если она не квадратная ей нужно дорисовать по бокам белые поля, что бы она стала квадратная. И сохранить

Простое изменение размеров, только растягивает картинку(

Может кто знает библиотеку которая способна это сделать или решение с помощью стандартных средств Жава, был бы очень благодарен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо взять размеры картинки. Выбрать максимальный размер. Создать квадратный offscreen canvas. Залить его белым цветом. Расчитать сдвиг левого верхнего угла с учётом разницы высоты (или ширины). Нарисовать картинку на canvas'е со сдвигом. Прочитать готовое изображение из canvas'а.

Comment: спасибо, будем пробовать)

Comment: сделал не через канвас, но по тому же принципу.